# Which function can I use in opencv as max() in matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, matrix, max

In MATLAB:

```
max(image,0)
```

sets the negative values to zero.  Is there any available function in OpenCV to do the same?

Comment: Probably not, but its extremely easy to code. Just iterate the Matrix values and if they are smaller than 0 set them to zero. Its 4 lines of  code LITERALLY. In Matlab using builtin functions for matrixes is faster than element-wise iteration, but in C++ there is no problem in iterating.

Comment: @AnderBiguri no need to iterate, you can use Mat Expressions (MatExpr). See my answer below ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually the exact same syntax works:

```
Mat im = cv::imread("...");
Mat im_capped = cv::max(im, 0);
```

Or if you want give it a matrix of zeros of the same size:

```
Mat thresh(im.size(), im.type(), Scalar::all(0));
Mat im_capped = cv::max(im, thresh);
```

According to the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#max):

[image: cv::max]

Comment: This is the right answer. Mine is correct, but this is exactly what the OP is asking :D

Comment: hmmm.. Now I'm thinking.. which method is faster?

Comment: well here is the source code for [`Mat::setTo`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/copy.cpp#L412), and here is [`cv::max`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp#L1079) (actually it calls a generic function `binary_op` which implements many similar binary operators)

Comment: ok the `im<0` part will create sort of a delayed matrix expression (see [`matop.cpp`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/matop.cpp#L917)), which will eventually call [`cv::compare`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp#L2855) when evaluated. That's the last piece of the puzzle :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like:

```
Mat im = ReadSomeImage(...);
Mat masked = im.setTo(0,im<0); /// <<<
```

`setTo(0,im<0)` does what you need.

Comment: Would http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#MatExpr%20max%28const%20Mat&%20a,%20double%20s%29 also work?

Comment: @Trilarion: yes it would :)

Comment: Oops, even better! :)